# Amcharts4, move label in percent

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

i try to place a label in my chart ...
the Y placement is fixed ( like -70 ... )
but i want to use a % placement for the X position...

so based on the official exemple : https://www.amcharts.com/demos/animated-gauge/
( you can open it in jsfiddle ou codepen like you want )

set the `label.y = -70;` (line 75 ) move the value up ...
but if you edit the line 75 with another value, the value didn't move to the right or left ...

So how can i place this label with % value ?

Answer (score 0):

> For the sprite to be able to use percent values for positions, the parent of the sprite should be of a fixed or percent width. radarContainer for the layout reasons does not have this. So for the percent to work, you might need to add labels to `chartContainer` instead of `radarContainer`, although you might need to do some adjustments to positions in order the label to be aligned with the radar.

CF: official support responce...